$z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ are complex such that $a, b, c$ satisfy $\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}} = \frac{a+bw+cw^2}{a+b+c}$ $|z_{1}-z_{2}|=4, |z_{1}-z_{2}w|=5 $
Let $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ are two complex numbers such that there exist positive real numbers $a, b, c$ satisfying $$\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}} = \frac{a+bw+cw^2}{a+b+c}$$ $$|z_{1}-z_{2}|=4, |z_{1}-z_{2}w|=5, |z_{1}-z_{2}w^2|=3 $$
$w$ denotes non real cube root of unity.
Find the value of $|z_{2}|$
My Approach
Looking at the values of mod given, I considered a right angled triangle made up from three different complex numbers. Using vector addition, I could prove that two of the complex numbers making up the right angled triangle would be equal to the third complex number. Equating this in equation yielded $z_{1} = 0$ through which I got $|z_{2}|=4$. Unfortunately I do not have the answer to this question so I wanted to know if what I did was correct and if not, how do I proceed?

if $z_1=0$ $|z_1-z_2\omega|=|z_2|=4\neq5$

Notice that $z_2, z_2w$ and $z_2w^2$ form an equilateral triangle $ABC$ with side $a =|z_2w-z_2|$ on circle with center at $0$ and radius $r=|z_2|$. Notice that point $D$ represented with $z_1$ lies inside this circle. Rotate $D$ around $A$ clockvise for $60^{\circ}$ in to $E$. Then triangle $BDE$ is right with $\angle BED = 90^{\circ}$, so $\angle BEA = 150^{\circ}$. By the law of cosine for triangle $BEA$ we get $$a^2 =3^2+4^2 -2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot \cos \angle 150^{\circ} =25+12\sqrt{3}$$
So $$|z_2|^2|w-1|^2 =25+12\sqrt{3}$$
which gives $$|z_2| =\sqrt{25+12\sqrt{3}\over 3}$$

Can you explain why you rotated D around A and how that resulted into $\angle BEA = 150^{\circ}$

Triangle $EDA$ is also equilateral.

First we trivially see that
$$
|a+b\omega+c\omega^2|\le|a|+|b|+|c|=|a+b+c|
$$
So $$|z_2|>|z_1|\quad(1)$$
Now note 2 identities
$$
|z_1-z_2|^2+|z_1-z_2\omega|^2+|z_1-z_2\omega^2|^2=3|z_1|^2+3|z_2|^2\quad(2)\\\quad\quad \text{(by using}\quad|x|^2=x\bar{x} \text{)}
$$
$$
|z_1-z_2|^4+|z_1-z_2\omega|^4+|z_1-z_2\omega^2|^4=3|z_1|^4+3|z_2|^4+12|z_1|^2|z_2|^2\quad(3)\\\quad\quad 
$$
Though the derivation might look long most of the work is alleviated by the fact that most of the terms go to zero as $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$
Substituting the given values in (2),(3) we get
$$
|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=\frac{50}3\\
|z_1|^4+|z_2|^4+4|z_1|^2|z_2|^2=\frac{962}3
$$
Solving this system you get a quadratic in terms of $|z_1|^2,|z_2|^2$
Taking positive values and using (1) we get
$$
|z_1|=\sqrt{\frac{25}3-4\sqrt{3}}\\ \ \\
|z_2|=\sqrt{\frac{25}3+4\sqrt{3}}
$$
